# Ubuntu 14.04 setup for Canoscan 9000 Mark II

Tags: scanner

How do I get sane to work on Ubuntu 14.04 with a USB 3 connected Canoscan 9000F Mark II scanner

`lsusb` shows the device as a `Canon Device 0x04A9/0x190d`. 
I added this device to `/etc/sane.d/canon-dr.conf`

`scanimage -d` test -T works with all passes

`sudo scanimage -L` fails to find the device

`sudo sane-find-scanner` fails to find the device

`sudo scanimage -d` sane-canon_dr -T says this is an invalid device

Answer (score 0):

Canoscan 9000 Mark II is using sane-pixma backend, so editing `/etc/sane.d/canon-dr.conf` is wrong.
See [SANE Supported Scanners database](http://www.sane-project.org/cgi-bin/driver.pl?manu=Canon&model=&bus=usb&v=04a9&p=190d) for more info.

**WARNING**: Following is NOT The Right Way™ to do things!

I got mine to work by updating my udev, libsane and libusb from Debian's Testing version. I don't know, if some of them wasn't necessary.

Like this in terminal:

```
$ sudo echo "deb <mirror> testing main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
# Sources are not necessary but here they are if wanted
$ sudo echo "deb-src <mirror> testing main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
$ sudo apt-key --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 46925553
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install udev libsane libusb-1.0-0
```

Debians [<mirror>'s](http://www.debian.org/mirror/list).

Do NOT use atp-get upgrade, because it's about The Best Way™ to destroy your Ubuntu installation. Do remember to remove or comment out those repositories from /etc/apt/sources.list afterwards.

```
$ sudo <put your preferred text editor here> /etc/apt/sources.list
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Took me some time to revert this. My udev paket was shown broken, with no easy way to fix it. It worked by downgrading the paket in synaptic to the ubuntu version. Though this also deinstalled some other pakets (sane, wine, ...).