# canoscan 9000f mark II on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: scanner

I am trying to install the CanoScan 900F Mark II on Ubuntu 14.04. Using the hints from [Ubuntu 14.04 setup for Canoscan 9000 Mark II](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455476/ubuntu-14-04-setup-for-canoscan-9000-mark-ii), I am able to detect the scanner and scanimage -L shows the correct device. However, when I try to do a test scan, I get an error "scanimage: reading one scanline, 1914 bytes... FAIL Error: Error during device I/O".

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you unlocked the physical lock button?